# Run code from current active cell to not overwrite previous cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have developed the following code to select the next empty cell, but it will not run the rest of my code, which checks columns.

When I run the code, it overwrites my previous work. I want the code to find the next empty cell and run from there, ignoring the previous cells. The bottom half of the code worked before trying to select the first empty cell.

```
Sub Outcome()
Dim Action As String
Dim Status As String
Dim Module As String
Dim Outcome As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim a As Integer

Application.Goto Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Offset(1), Scroll:=True

For x = Active.Cell To 500 ---> (First blank cell to 500)
Action = Cells(x, 5).Value
Status = Cells(x, 8).Value
Module = Cells(x, 9).Value
Outcome = Cells(x, 10).Value


If Action = "" Then Exit Sub

If Action = " Page was incorrectly blocked" And Status = "NOT BLOCKED" And Module = "NOT BLOCKED" Then Outcome = "No Action" Else
If Action = " Page was incorrectly blocked" And Status = "BLOCKED" And Module = "caravan" Then Outcome = "Check" Else
If Action = " Page was incorrectly blocked" And Status = "BLOCKED" And Module = "Holiday" Then Outcome = "Refer to Nominum" Else
If Action = " Page was incorrectly blocked" And Status = "" And Module = "" Then Outcome = "Check" Else


If Action = " Page was incorrectly blocked (caravan)" And Status = "NOT BLOCKED" And Module = "NOT BLOCKED" Then Outcome = "No Action" Else
If Action = " Page was incorrectly blocked (caravan)" And Status = "BLOCKED" And Module = "caravan" Then Outcome = "Check" Else
If Action = " Page was incorrectly blocked (caravan)" And Status = "BLOCKED" And Module = "Holiday" Then Outcome = "Refer to Nominum" Else
If Action = " Page was incorrectly blocked (caravan)" And Status = "" And Module = "" Then Outcome = "Check" Else


If Action = " Page was incorrectly blocked (Malware)" And Status = "NOT BLOCKED" And Module = "NOT BLOCKED" Then Outcome = "No Action" Else
If Action = " Page was incorrectly blocked (Malware)" And Status = "BLOCKED" And Module = "Holiday" Then Outcome = "Refer to Nominum" Else
If Action = " Page was incorrectly blocked (Malware)" And Status = "BLOCKED" And Module = "caravan" Then Outcome = "Check" Else
If Action = " Page was incorrectly blocked (Malware)" And Status = "" And Module = "" Then Outcome = "Check" Else


If Action = " This page should be blocked." And Status = "NOT BLOCKED" And Module = "NOT BLOCKED" Then Outcome = "Check" Else
If Action = " This page should be blocked." And Status = "BLOCKED" And Module = "caravan" Then Outcome = "No Action" Else
If Action = " This page should be blocked." And Status = "BLOCKED" And Module = "Holiday" Then Outcome = "Refer to Nominum" Else
If Action = " This page should be blocked." And Status = "" And Module = "" Then Outcome = "Check" Else

Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply `For x = Active.Cell To 500` will not work at all... `Active.Cell` would assume that `Active` is a range (but you never declared it like that). Either do it like that:

```
For x = Selection.Row To Selection.Row + 500
```

Or run it as a range like:

```
Dim xx as Variant
For each xx in Selection.Resize(500, 1).Cells
```

then `xx` will be the cell itself.

Also clean up your huge `IF` block... it ends with an `Else` and should trigger a syntax error! (But it does not... unfortunately)

**EDIT**:

For your 4 `If` blocks:

```
If Action = " Page was incorrectly blocked" Or Action = " Page was incorrectly blocked (caravan)" Or Action = " Page was incorrectly blocked (Malware)" Or Action = " This page should be blocked." Then
  If Status = "BLOCKED" And Module = "Holiday" Then
    Outcome = "Refer to Nominum"
  ElseIf Status = "" And Module = "" Then
    Outcome = "Check"
  ElseIf Status = "NOT BLOCKED" And Module = "NOT BLOCKED" Then
    If Action = " This page should be blocked." Then Outcome = "Check" Else Outcome = "No Action"
  ElseIf Status = "BLOCKED" And Module = "caravan" Then
    If Action = " This page should be blocked." Then Outcome = "No Action" Else Outcome = "Check"
  End If
End If
```